# How to add module to Play! Framework 2.4

Tags: scala, module, routes, playframework-2.4

I'm trying to separate some application logic into modules. 
I've created module which is supposed to handle users (view profile etc. (models + controllers))

I've added module into reference.conf

```
play.modules.enabled += "modules.users"
```

But when I try to access app:

```
Module [modules.users] cannot be instantiated.
```

Is creating [Custom loader](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaCompileTimeDependencyInjection#Application-entry-point) only option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This syntax works only with **runtime** dependency injection: the configuration is read at runtime, and the required modules are loaded.

The module "name" must reference a [`Guice Module`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaDependencyInjection#Programmatic-bindings), where you define your custom bindings.

One full example:

*conf/application.conf*

```
play.modules.enabled += "auth.di.AuthModule"
```

*modules/auth/app/di/AuthModule.scala*

```
package auth.di

class AuthModule extends AbstractModule {

   def configure() = {
       // Binds your services here
   }
}
```

*build.sbt*

```
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .enablePlugins(PlayScala)
  .dependsOn(moduleAuth).aggregate(moduleAuth)

lazy val moduleAuth = (project in file("modules/auth"))
   .enablePlugins(PlayScala)
```

Tips: Use [scala-guice](https://github.com/codingwell/scala-guice) to define your modules more fluently.